# "Error 404: not found" in magento frontend and also the admin

Tags: magento

How to remove the error 404: not found on magento frontend and admin plz suggestion me
i m using the magento 1.9 and the check image below link="http://postimg.org/image/o85a0decf/"

Comment: Hi hardik Error 404 is the error for page not found. you have to clearify more what did you do so that this error shows.

Comment: add this extension "http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-zoom-plus.html" then i configuration after i open magento then error comes and the Administrators / Roles / Permissions / System / Magento Admin then i save it.

Comment: The extension your trying to use is not compatible with magento version 1.9.

Comment: i can not open backend then how can i remove this extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@HARDIKGOHIL : you can remove extension from your downloader link, if your backend is not working then also it downloader link will open and you have to login with same your backend username and password.

e.g yourdomain/downloader/

you will get list of modules of magento default as well as you have configured, un-install the module